# Android Studio - Close Icon of a Chip does not do anything (Java)

Tags: java, android, view

I created some `Chips` and they have an X symbol on the right side. 
But when I click the X (intending to dismiss or remove the Chip), nothing happens. 
I tried to use the method `setOnCloseIconClickListener` but it did not have an effect. 
I click the X icon and the color of the icon changes and a clicking sound appears, but the Chip View remains on the screen. 
And I also don't know what to write in the callback method of the click listener.

```
        for(int i = 0; i<products.length; i++) {
            //the chip component requires your app theme to be Theme.MaterialComponents (or a
            //descendant)
            chips[i] = new Chip(this);
            //ScrollView can only host one direct child
            ll1.addView(chips[i]);
            chips[i].setText(products[i]);
            chips[i].setCloseIconVisible(true);
        }
```

I tried this, but it said the variable i has to be final which is not possible cause i is incrementing.

```
            chips[i].setOnCloseIconClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    chips[i].close();
                }
            });
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found the solution. This is the code:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener {

    private EditText et1;
    private ScrollView sv1;
    private LinearLayout ll1;
    private Chip[] chips;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        et1 = findViewById(R.id.editText);
        sv1 = findViewById(R.id.scrollView);
        ll1 = new LinearLayout(this);
        ll1.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);
        sv1.addView(ll1);
    }

    public void splitToChips(View v) {
        String content = et1.getText().toString();
        String[] products = content.split(";");

        chips = new Chip[products.length];

        for(int i = 0; i<products.length; i++) {
            chips[i] = new Chip(this);
            ll1.addView(chips[i]);
            chips[i].setText(products[i]);
            chips[i].setCloseIconVisible(true);
            chips[i].setOnCloseIconClickListener(this);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        Chip chip = (Chip) v;
        ll1.removeView(chip);
    }
}
```